# Most used social bookmarking sites for sharing?

Tags: wordpress, links, social-media

A lot of WordPress sites have a "share this post to xxx" link. I was wondering which "xxx" people click the most? A top 5 or something like that.

I know Twitter and Facebook are in the list, but are there any others sites that are popular when it comes to sharing links?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list of sites which is not on-topic here

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the most popular still seems to be email (I know it's not exactly a social sit but I thought it was worth mentioning since people seem to be around 2x as likely to share via email for most of the sites I manage) followed by either twitter or Facebook. Then it varies between stumbleupon, delicious and Digg depending on the target market (although digg seems to be decreasing in popularity and reddit seems to be increasing).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.addthis.com/services#cat=bookmarking shows stats from addthis.com. They're not a bad place to start

Comment: I'd agree with this, although the "All" option is probably better: http://www.addthis.com/services#cat=

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on your target. But I guess some good suggestions could be Delicious, StumbleUpon, Reddit, Digg.

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://gs.statcounter.com/

You can filter by social media, and your country.

Comment: Very interesting +1